# Save processed image in iPhone library

Tags: iphone, xcode, image-processing, cgaffinetransform, flip

I am using this code to flip image.

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, -1, 1);
imageView.transform = trans;
```

Now if i want to save this flipped image what should i do ?
I am using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, nil, nil, nil);` to save the image in iphone library but it is saving the original image not the flipped image.

Your suggestions are welcome guys.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As You're doing you're flipping `UIImageView` on its `X-Axis` not `UIImage`. So obviously code would save your original image.

Flip your `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView` then save -

```
 UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

Now use your saving method -

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(flippedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)tapFlipXPosition:(id)sender
{
    UIImage* sourceImage = yourSourceImage;
    UIImage* flippedImage;

    if(sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUpMirrored)
    {
       flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
    }
    else
    {
        flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    }

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(flippedImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response Vakul. I tried this before. The problem is, it flips the image at first time but if i tap button second time it does nothing. I mean continuous flip is not working here. Any suggestion on it ?

Comment: You didn't mention it any where in your question that you want to make a flipping button action..... You can use toggling for this.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code. Here first you would take a screenshot of the inverted Image, save it into another imageviewView and then save this particular "New Image" to the PhotoLibrary.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(BaseView.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *attachimage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:Data];
    UIImage *viImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    attachimage = viImage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting he take a screenshot of an image that he already has?

Comment: That's kind of the point of voting. Your answer is bad, so I downvoted it. If you provide a good answer I upvote it.